# Kubuntu 20.04 is slow when running on HDD & micro stuttering

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, hard-drive, performance

My brand new installation of Kubuntu 20.04 is having micro-stutter when installed on the HDD. While on LIVE USB, It is very smooth & snappy.Performance is degraded while installed in HDD is noticeable for every click. Apps openings are also painfully slow. Even Dolphin taking 3-5 seconds to open(No files in MY HDD).

Hardware configuration:

- Intel i5 3rd gen
- 16 GB RAM
- 1 TB HDD

In Live USB, IDLE RAM is around 1.3 GB,After installation in HDD RAM usage is 0.3 GB.Since I have more RAM, How to force Kubuntu to use more RAM for Performance??
Note: I have installed all the latest updates. I also Tried KDE neon, having exact same issue, Working smooth on LIVE USB not after installation in HDD

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing the HDD is a way to solve the issue. The thing is live USB is that all apps are loaded in the ram rather than storage. So the ram usage is higher. If you want your system to use more ram go for UBUNTU, which is likely to be more resource hungry and thus, uses more ram.

As you know SSD is faster. Switching to SSD will make the system snappy.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! I installed this OS on the new HDD & I know apps are loaded in  RAM during LIVE Boot, but I want to  know, is there any way to force OS to load apps in the RAM?